CSS: how to let the children elements' font fallback to its parent's font family?
We're working on a html reader, and the content could be any html. We want to set a default font family if the font set in the content is not available.
For example,
<body style="font-family: A"><div style="font-family: B"></div></body>

If font B is not available, I prefer to use A to render. But we're not able to change the style on div since it's user content.
Or if it's possible to change browser's default fallback font?

Main problem: The browser applies the font-family property according to the most specific CSS rule (In your case the inline style attribute in <div>).
If the actual font can't be applied (if the font isn't loaded via @font-face rules or not available as a locally installed font) it still applies this CSS rule.
In other words: the browser won't search for available fonts specified in parent element style rules.
So there is no way to force the browser to apply/prefer an actually available font for display e.g by traversing the complete CSS to find the best candidate – the cascade and specificity concept of CSS just doesn't work this way.
Here's an example:


body{
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

div{
    font-family: 'None existent Sans', 'None existent Slab';
}
test
<div style="font-family: 'None existent Sans'">Div content</div>



The best you could do to keep the rendered HTML styling to some extent consistent is to override the <div> font styles via a more specific parent rule. E.g by using a more specific selector and/or adding the !important keyword.


@font-face{
  font-family: Montserrat;
  src: url('https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/montserrat/v24/JTUHjIg1_i6t8kCHKm4532VJOt5-QNFgpCtr6Hw5aXo.woff2') format('woff2')
}

body, html body * {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif!important;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

div{
    font-family: 'None existent Sans', 'None existent Slab';
}
<p>Hamburgefons</p>
<div style="font-family: 'None existent Sans'">Div content <div style="font-family: 'None existent Sans'">Sub Div content</div></div>



Remap font-families to default
To some extent you may also remap some font-famies to a default font via @font-face


body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'None existent Sans';
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Arial')
}

div {
  font-family: 'None existent Sans', 'None existent Slab';
}
test
<div style="font-family: 'None existent Sans'">Div content</div>



This takes for granted you can predict an array of commonly used fonts. At best you are able to replace some undesired font-families (e.g Comic Sans).
In a perfect world, we would be able to use JS method check() ... From mdn docs:

Nonexistent fonts   If we specify a font that is not in the FontFaceSet and is not a system font, check() returns true, because in
this situation we will not rely on any fonts from the set:

So it's rather useless.

Thanks! That's also what I have known. Overriding the origin style on the user content with !important is just too much for us. We'd like to respect the style in user content if possible. It means we may need to traverse all elements in the user content and try to add a fallback font on font-family. I just want to ask the question here to confirm if that's the only feasible way.

You may also "intercept" known fonts provided you can predict at least some used fonts. I've added some details. Frankly, I believe that retaining user-defined styling most often introduces a lot of problems as it might break your main page design. Without an ability to embed custom fonts there's not much left from the original user-styling anyway. To save you some time: check() JS method also doesn't work to detect not available fonts. Sorry, for curbing your enthusiasm!

That should be the default behavior. Font is calculated in this order getting the first availabe:

The desired font.
The earliest available one from the font-fallbacks (font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;).
The parent's font or the closest parent's font going up in the DOM tree getting the first available.
The browser's original font.


<body style="font-family: A">
    <div style="font-family: inherit; font-family: B;">
    </div>
</body>

You can set the CSS property as above, if B is valid, the browser will apply the last one, if not, the browser will ignore the invalid property.
